# Bash (Mint): How to add a newline to a PS3 prompt?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying this stupid code

```
PS3="Choose 1..10\n0 to exit";
```

But bash shows me literally `\n`, and not a new line.

I'm trying to use it in a bash script with select a 'builtin' choice prompt.

Comment: `echo -e $PS3` will print the newline. From man pages: `-e enable interpretation of backslash escapes`

Comment: I'm trying to use it in a bash script with select a 'builtin' choice prompt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ PS3="Choose 1..10"$'\n'"0 to exit: "
$ select choice in $(seq 10)
> do
> [[ $choice -eq 0 ]] && break
> #do stuff for choice 1 to 10
> done
 1) 1
 2) 2
 3) 3
 4) 4
 5) 5
 6) 6
 7) 7
 8) 8
 9) 9
10) 10
Choose 1..10
0 to exit: 0
$
```

Just an additional `$'\n'` is required wrt `bash` context, which is inserted in between the `PS3` environment variable. It's similar to the way we set it for `IFS`

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: Since you don't need any parameter expansion inside the prompt, you can write this more simply as `PS3=$'Choose 1..10\n0 to exit: '`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also embed a newline in a string directly:

```
PS3="Choose 1..10
0 to exit: "
```

Comment: And you win ... I was so simply that I've not tried

Comment: if you put a color code inside quote, you have to use as this $'color code ~~~ text '